# Apache2 forward proxy: What is the relationship between the 'Require' directive in proxy.conf versus the directive defined in my VirtualHosts config?

Tags: apache, proxy

I've followed [this guide](https://geek-university.com/configure-apache-as-a-forward-proxy/) to setup a forward proxy on a server. I'm not understanding some of the configurations that were applied during the process. In `proxy.conf` in Apache's `mods_enabled` directory contains the block

```
<Proxy *>
    ...
    Require all deny
    ...
</Proxy>
```

My understanding is that this Require directive should deny any connections to this proxy. However after defining a VirtualHosts config with a Proxy block containing the allowed IPs, my clients are able to connect to the proxy just fine. Is there a order of operations in which these definitions are read or are they two completely separate things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being mislead by your distros use of multiple configuration files, which are meaningless to Apache.  Apache cares about the context of a directive only (global, or in sections delimited by `<>`, or htaccess)

Directives in VirtualHost context, including sections like `<Proxy>`, have higher precedence than directives in global scope (no enclosing config section).

Other more ambiguous sections have precedence rules here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html